# How to make List of Unique data from multiple List containing duplicate values

Tags: java, collections

In Java.
I have 3 **List** and all contains duplicate values like.

```
List<Integer> list1=1,2,3,4
List<Integer> list2=2,3,4,5

List<Integer> list3=1,4,5,6
```

I want to make a single `List<Integer> list=1,2,3,4,5,6`

Is it possible to do without using loops.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you use looks like Java, so this is how you could do it in Java:

```
TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet();
set.addAll(list1);
set.addAll(list2);
set.addAll(list3);
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(set);
```

Comment: Clean and simple :) there you go.

Answer (score -1):

To not use loops, use recursive calls of functions. You can use a hash array, or an object and set its properties with your values, use "true" value for simplicity.

When you override, its not a problem, it will just get re-set as true.

Afterwards, you loop through the hash array or object and all its properties are unique (and all have the value true).

If you have a particular language of programming, mention it as a comment, I might give you the function to do it.

Comment: thanks. I forgot to mention language, I am using java please tell me predefined functions if possible. thanks